# How to fix <h1> centering issue on responsive page

Tags: html, css

On screen widths greater than 840 pixels wide, the h1 on this responsive page is not centered properly:

https://www.versionmuseum.com/history-of/mac-os-9-setup

The left side nav appears once the width is greater than 840.

The current h1 tag looks like this:

```
<h1 style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;">The Mac OS 9 Installer is an Amazing Internet Time Capsule</h1>
```

It remains uncentered when stripping out the word-wrap and white-space style, as seen in this version of the page:

https://www.versionmuseum.com/not-centered.html

Any idea how to properly center it? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: your h1 has a before pseudo element has a width of 150 which is causing your issue. See the class: header.major > :first-child:before, header.major > :first-child:after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it works if you remove `content`.

```
header.major > :first-child::before, header.major > :first-child::after
...
content: '';
```

> main.css 2064

Comment: Nice, this appears to work! Thank you! I'm testing across different browsers and widths right now.

Comment: All tests pass! Looks great, thanks for your help. I upvoted it but my reputation score is too low for it to count, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with [this class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLKFf.png), that set a fix width. Take this off or override and the problem is solved.

Comment: The problem is not in <h1> itself, is in the header

Comment: Interesting, but I'm still having problems with centering on screen widths between 840 and 1280.

Comment: have you tried to remove the "content" property from that class?

Comment: Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow. Your answer is valuable; but please avoid using images as code snippets. This reduces the readability and reachability of both questions and answers alike. Try editing your answer and add code snippets, wrapping in single backtick ` ` ` for inline or triple backticks ` ``` ` for code blocks. You can always check [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more formatting options.